# Qt and OpenGL for game development

Tags: qt, opengl

I have a few questions about Qt.

1. I already know that Qt and OpenGL can be used together. At the
   moment we are using GLUT at my university (for window and input
   management). I saw that Qt is able to do the same thing. **Are there
   any disadvantages of using Qt instead of GLUT?** *(performance
   wise)*
2. I also know that Qt can be used to build a ingame GUI. I even saw
   this 3d GUI example [WolfenQt](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MXS3xKV-UM0). So it is possible. **But does it
   make sense to use Qt for an ingame GUI if you care about
   perfomance?**

Comment: Is there even a 64 bit version of glut for windows? I believe it is no longer in development and is not opensource. QT is a good cross platform toolkit and is still in current development. There's really no reason for comparison. The school's still use glut because it's a popular library for teaching 3D programming not because it provides the best performance. Besides most of the performance will come from opengl not a widget library.

Comment: @Codeguy007: There's FreeGLUT, which is open source and well maintained. And yes there are Win64 builds for it. However I'd not recomment GLUT for a game. Better use SDL or GLFW.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Qt, like any other tool can be misused. But just because you use Qt this does not mean, OpenGL performance will suffer. OpenGL doesn't care about what and how its context and the drawable it's bound to are created. The biggest impact Qt has is, how it manages and delivers events; the signal/slots mechanism.

Comment: Why would you choose GLFW over QT for games? Because QT uses events and GLFW c callbacks?

Comment: @MaikKlein: GLFW does not use callbacks, as does SDL (I think you mean GLUT, which is a different framework). It puts the whole event loop in your hand. Which is exactly what you want for a game! Qt passes around signals which are collected in a queue in the mainloop which are then dispatched to the slots they're connected to. This makes latencies a bit unpredictable. In most cases you won't notice, but sometimes… The point is, with GLFW and SDL you have precise control about event management, order of operations and timing. With Qt you don't.

Comment: @datenwolf: Events and signals/slots usually are unrelated. Almost all signals/slots are basically calls to methods and never go through the event loop at all. Only in multithreaded setups the event loop gets involved. So your statements collapses to "do not do too much stuff or your latencies will suffer", which is true with any framework.

Comment: @TobiasHunger: Indeed. However most games *are* multithreaded and then things get interesting; independent of the framework used.

Comment: Using ONE thread for window management with Custom loop that calls ProcessEvents() before Render() [basically, writing own game loop] allows you direct control over Qt's one :)