# Game engine in OpenGL with GLFW and Qt?

Tags: qt, opengl, game-engine, glfw

I started a similar question several months ago [Qt and OpenGL for game development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892384/qt-and-opengl-for-game-development)

At the moment I am not really sure what I should do. I often read that it is not recommended to use Qt for games, instead GLFW would be better suited for this task. I am not completely sure why but I think I will be on the safe side if I choose GLFW.

But I want to use Qt for the editor. The editor should be WYSIWYG, like many other game engines are. So that you can jump into the game at any given time.

Is it possible to use Qt and GLFW in the same project?

Comment: "I am not completely sure why but I think I will be on the safe side if I choose GLFW."  Before you start a big project, I really recommend your assumptions about it's core architecture are correct...

Comment: @cmannett85: In Maik Klein's defense: Qt really is a horrible base for a interactive, low latency game. It's even a PITA if you have to do advanced multidrawable multithreaded OpenGL stuff, like I had to experience recently.

Comment: FYI: City of Heroes used Qt in their game.

Comment: @Jay: Yes it can be done, but you've to navigate around some really strange problems sometimes. Most people probably won't get into trouble, but sometimes it's madness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use Qt and GLFW in the same project?

No. But why would you? You can use GLFW for your standalone engine and Qt for the editor. It's even possible to replace the QCoreApplication event loop with something custom. Just make sure that your code is not too tightly coupled to a certain framework.

Comment: I thought about this too, that I just render to Qt in the editor and use GLFW for the standalone version. But I was a little bit worried that it would be inconsistent. For example the game would run different in the editor then it would in the stand alone version. Take at look at http://www.mycrysis.com/sites/default/files/wysiwyg/images/Crymod/90dd8d1a272ae592e5d4bb1a586d9ab5.jpg I thought I could use GLFW for the "ingame window" and just use Qt for the rest (widgets etc). Don't you think that this could be possible?

Comment: Well, you can't embedd a GLFW window into a Qt and also GLFW's and Qt's event loops would tread on each other toes. But it's very simple to write a small abstraction layer that can attach to a overridden QCoreApplication event loop and derived QGLWidget, or to a GLFW.

Comment: @user63898: I think you may want to have messaged Maik Klein. For that you need to use an @-addressing. Like this: `@MaikKlein`

Comment: @MaikKlein: I think user63898 intended to message you.