# Connecting GLFW to QOpenGLWidget

Tags: c++, qt, glfw

I'm trying to connect GLFW application to Qt QOpenGLWidget, but I can't figure out is it possible and if it's possible, how to do this?

Comment: You are aware that GLFW is mainly a window managing API? I don't think that QT would let you specify your own window handling.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732930/game-engine-in-opengl-with-glfw-and-qt) question for more information.

Comment: I think you'll need to explain more clearly what you mean by "connect GLFW application to Qt QOpenGLWidget".  If you can't provide a [MCVE] then perhaps show the code that you would *like* to be able to write.

Comment: If you are planning to use Qt then there is no point of using GLFW.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit late for an answer, anyway:

**GLFW** is a library provides an API for **creating windows, contexts and surfaces, receiving input and events**. Qt already does it for you. (with additional GL functions)

So it is not possible to use Qt with GLFW. Almost everything that GLFW provides could be found inside Qt libraries. For example: to specify major/minor version you can use **QSurfaceFormat**, etc.

I think it's worth to mention that Qt works with other OpenGL bindings. 
I use PyOpenGL with Qt with no problems instead built-in Qt functions. Works perfectly.